# Argument1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int' error in List

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code

```
public static List<int> GetAllYear()
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(strXmlPath);
    XmlNodeList nodeList = document.SelectNodes("Year");
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
    {
        list.Add(node.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString()); //This line throws error
    }
    return list;
}
```

when I try to build the solution I get the following error:

```
Argument1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'
```

Honestly I do not know why because when I return the result to the list variable I use the ToString() to convert it explicitly.  Could someone help me understand what is going on here.  I can post more code if needed.

I have tried to just google the error message and it seems to be a generic error message but no one really explains the reason for the error.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Read the error more carefully.  `ToString()` will not convert to `int`.  You want `int.Parse()`.

Comment: I had tried int.Parse() and it did not work either.  Habib and the others have the correct answers

Comment: The safest way is using `Int32.TryParse` - check out my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your list is `List<int>` and you are trying to add a string value to your `List`, you can't do that.

You can parse the string to `int` using `int.Parse` or `Convert.ToInt32` or safely using `int.TryParse`

If your `Value` contains integer value then you can explicitly cast it like:

```
list.Add((int) node.Attributes["name"].Value);
```

or you can use:

```
list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["name"].Value));
```

Comment: @MaximusPrime, You are welcome, I know you didn't :). All the downvotes now seems to have been retracted.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add a string into a list that can only contain int's

You need to parse the string into an int like so...

```
list.Add(int.Parse(node.Attributes["name"].Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add a `string` value into a List of type `int`. You have to convert the string value (if possible) into int before adding to the list. I recommend you this way (`using Int32.TryParse`) to avoid unexpected exceptions in case you found a string that cannot be converted to int.

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(node.Attributes["name"].Value, out number);
if (result) list.Add(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list is of type `int`, so you should convert the value which you want to add to an `int`:

```
list.Add(int.Parse(node.Attributes["name"].Value));
```